# Is WorldBet a superset of Arpabet?

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Does WorldBet contain all of the phonemes that Arpabet has? And do they mean the same thing in WorldBet? E.g. "AO" code in WorldBet is pronounced the same as "AO" in Arpabet, and so on for every phoneme in Arpabet.

Comment: Is this at all useful? http://www.csee.ogi.edu/~gormanky/papers/codes/

Comment: Very helpful. From that chart, I can see that a mapping is required from Arpabet to WorldBet codes, and also that WorldBet probably covers Arpabet's codes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorldBet does contain codes representing all the phonemes that Arpabet represents. So in that sense, WorldBet is a superset of Arpabet. However, a phoneme represented by an Arpabet code may have a different WorldBet code.

To find a mapping from an Arpabet code to a WorldBet code corresponding to the same phoneme, see the table at this URL: http://www.csee.ogi.edu/~gormanky/papers/codes/

Comment: Thanks to Paul for the link and Kyle Gorman at OHSU for the table. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone disagrees with or wants to improve upon my self-answer before choosing it as the answer.